# Scheme equivalent to Haskell where clause

Tags: haskell, scheme, racket

I am just learning scheme, but I would love to be able to repeat myself less.

Is there a way I can assign a name to a subexpression in the local scope?

As per the comment:

Haskell where clause

```
x = s * t 
  where s = 10
        t = 20
```

x should be 200 in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let (or letrec for recursive bindings), e.g.:

```
(define (f g) 
  (let ((x 1) (y (* g 2))) 
       (+ x y)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly in the "beginning language" subset of drscheme there is no `let`.  Still, obviously the correct answer.

Comment: If you know Haskell, you are probably better off with not using the "beginning language" subset of Drscheme. The entirety of scheme is already small, much smaller than Haskell.